# Why is my loop, that has to count substrings, not working correctly?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, count

I have two dataframes (20000+ rows) with combinations. I want to loop through df2 with df1 and count the occurence of combinations. For example the code should be able to recognize that the combination "B,D" from df1 occurces 3 times with these combinations of df2; "A,B,D" "B,C,D" "A,B,C,D". So the code should be able to look into the string and recognize that the letters "B,D" are in "A,B,C,D". I put my code below, what can I change about it so it counts the combinations right?

```
d1 = {'Combinations' : ['A,B', 'A,C', 'A,D', 'B,C', 'B,D', 'C,D', 'A,B,C', 'A,C,D', 'B,C,D', 'A,B,D', 'A,B,C,D',]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'Combinations' : ['A,B,D', 'A,C,D', 'B,C,D', 'A,B,C,D', 'A,D']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

counts = []

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    values = row['Combinations'].split(',')

    count = df2.Combinations.str.contains('|'.join(values)).sum()
    counts.append(count)
    
df1['counts'] = counts
```

Output from loop:

```
   Combinations  counts
0          A,B       5
1          A,C       5
2          A,D       5
3          B,C       4
4          B,D       5
5          C,D       5
6        A,B,C       5
7        A,C,D       5
8        B,C,D       5
9        A,B,D       5
10     A,B,C,D       5
```

Instead I want this (the correct) output from the loop:

```
   Combinations  counts
0          A,B       2
1          A,C       2
2          A,D       4
3          B,C       2
4          B,D       3
5          C,D       3
6        A,B,C       1
7        A,C,D       2
8        B,C,D       2
9        A,B,D       2
10     A,B,C,D       1
```

Comment: Was the `'|'.join(values)` meant to be `','.join(values)` by chance? I can not see the pipe symbol being used anywhere else.

Comment: The error probably comes from the fact that you are checking whether the column contains the JOINED values, but your question suggests you want to check that it contains EACH of the values, regardless of order. You might need to loop through the values and ensure that each is contained within a cell. If all values are within a cell, that cell should be counted.

Comment: Hi @HubertGrzeskowiak I changed the pipe symbol to ',' , but the count is still not accurate. Could you maybe provide a code of your suggestion to loop and ensuring each is contained within a cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to convert the `df2.Combinations` to a `set` and then test the elements against this set:

```py
df1.Combinations = df1.Combinations.str.split(",")
df2.Combinations = df2.Combinations.str.split(",").apply(set)

data = []
for l in df1.Combinations:
    data.append(sum(c.issuperset(l) for c in df2.Combinations))

df1["counts"] = data

print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
    Combinations  counts
0         [A, B]       2
1         [A, C]       2
2         [A, D]       4
3         [B, C]       2
4         [B, D]       3
5         [C, D]       3
6      [A, B, C]       1
7      [A, C, D]       2
8      [B, C, D]       2
9      [A, B, D]       2
10  [A, B, C, D]       1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
count = 0
for i in df1.Combinations:
   for j in df2.Combinations:
     if i in j:
        count += 1
   print( i "appears" + str(count) + "times")
```